# Spring JPA bean not found exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am using spring JPA in my project. My repository bean is not getting called. I get a null pointerException.

My Repository is:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

My entity URL:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    @Column(name = "emailid")
    String emailId;

    @Column(name="role")
    UserRole role;


}
```

My JPA Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "appentitymanagerfactory",
transactionManagerRef = "apptransactionmanager",
basePackages = "com.tree.employeeapp.entity")
public class JpaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    (name = "appentitymanagerfactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean externalEntityManagerFactory(
         EntityManagerFactoryBuilder   builder, @Qualifier("employeeappdatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.tree.employeeapp.entity")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "apptransactionmanager")
      public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("appentitymanagerfactory") EntityManagerFactory
        entityManagerFactory
      ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
      }
}
```

My controller is this:

```
@Controller
public class treeAppsControllerImpl implements treeAppsController{

private UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
public treeAppsControllerImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
public String getAllUsers(Model model) {
    List<Users> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    for(User user: userRepository.findAll())
            listOfUser.add(user);

    List<User> listOfUser = UserRepository.findAll();
    model.addAllAttributes(listOfUsers);
    return "getAllUsers";
}
```

the log shows this error:

**Parameter 0 of constructor in com.tree.employeeapp.controller.treeAppsControllerImpl required a bean of type 'com.tree.employeeapp.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tree.employeeapp.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.**

Comment: *Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tree.employeeapp.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.* did you define this? I notice you have both caps and camel case UserRepo in your code.

Comment: That is possible but i have read that when we use @EnableJPARepository, Spring automatically creates a bean of the extended interfaces of JPARepository. This is for one Repository layer. what if there are 20 different Repository DAO layers?

Comment: Is`UserRepository` actually in package, `com.tree.employeeapp.entity` as indicated in `@EnableJpaRepositories#basePackages`?

Comment: No it is in com.tree.employeeapp.repository

Comment: Then that should be where `basePackages` points.

Answer (score 0):

Mark UserRepository as Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
}
```